# German keyboard configuration: "STRG + ALT" shortcuts don't work

Tags: shortcut-keys, language-support

Since 1 hour ago I've been a proud Ubuntu user. But there is a problem I'm not able to solve:

The <kbd>STRG</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> shortcuts doesn't work (for example <kbd>STRG</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> = `@`).

I checked all German keyboard configurations I can choose from with no success.

I have the problem with every application.

<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> doesn't work either.

How can I get this working?

Comment: So Alt Gr+Q doesn't print an *@*?

Answer (score 2):

**Check your keyboard settings**

Click the top right symbol in the Panel, open the first entry of the popping up menu.
[image]

Open key settings.
[image]

Add a new keyboard.
[image]

Choose the right keyboard-settings. You can test them in the field below. Click "add".
[image]

To apply them push them upwards by clicking the arrow.
[image]

If this doesn't work you can reset everything by deleting this new keyboard-settings: Click them once and then click the "-".